# How to re-ask the user to enter Yes or No?

Tags: java, user-interface, text

A simple text game expects input from the user in a YES or NO format.
If the format is incorrect, the program should ask again.
I want the game to use different funny phrases instead of boring ones like "Please enter yes or no".

I know how to code it in Java but English is not my native language and I find it difficult to come up with such phrases. I would be glad if you can help me come up with these phrases in English. May be some ideas where I can find such phrases.

```
    private boolean askYesNo() {
        while (true) {
            final var answer = scanner.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
            if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'N') {
                return answer == 'Y';
            }
            System.out.println(pickMessage(new String[]{
                    "Come on, yes or no?",
                    "Please enter yes or no."
            }));
        }
    }

    private String pickMessage(final String[] messages) {
        return messages[random.nextInt(messages.length)];
    }
```

Comment: "Yea or nay", "Enter Y to continue", "Y not?"

Comment: I don't think Stackoverflow is the right place for a question like that.

Comment: Please read [what questions should you ask on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This is a QA website for programming topics and not for the English phrases. I wouldn't have answered if you're really looking for *English phrases*. I did, however, because you had a programming problems there and I thought I could help with that respect.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let's fix the few mistakes in your existing code:

1. You are missing an *else* block, which means, that lines after the *if* block will always execute;
2. Disregarding of whether the input is `Y` or `N`, you're assigning `answer == 'Y';` and returning that;
3. Returning uncasted (type is not inferred) type, which is expected to be a `Character` (so, you should cast it), yet your method declares to be returning completely different type - `boolean`.

---

Now let's select a random String element from your array, by also fixing existing problems:

```
private Character askYesNo() {
    while (true) {
        final char answer = scanner.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
        if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'N') {
            return answer;
        } else {
            pickMessage(messages); //assuming that you have a messages variable
        };
    }
}

private String pickMessage(final String[] messages) {
    Random random = new Random();
    return messages[random.nextInt(messages.length)];
}
```